# Создать таблицу для каждого пользователя или одну общую

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, таблицы

Хочу сделать историю каждого поиска каждого пользователя, как мне рациональней сделать, создать для каждого пользователя таблицу или одну общую. Пользователь может посмотреть свою историю.

Answer (score 5):

Ни в коем случае не стоит создавать для каждого пользователя отдельную таблицу.

**Одна таблица - для одного рода данных.**
Допустим, для пользователей. Для каждого нового пользователя просто добавляйте новый ряд в таблицу с пользователями, нет нужды создавать новые таблицы.

Начните с этого - https://habr.com/ru/post/514364/

Comment: Я походу не коректно выразился. Будет таблица со всеми пользователями(их данные: id, имя и т.д.). И будет отдельная таблица их истории поиска. Мне для этого создать одну общую историю и потом по запросу пользователя(хочет посмотреть свою историю) делать выборку из этой таблицы или для каждого пользователя создать свою таблицу с историей. Предпологается что в истории будет много записей.

Comment: Рациональнее будет создать 1 таблицу, в которой вы будете хранить всю историю пользователей. В каждой записи сохраняйте id пользователя, после чего делайте выборку. Одну таблицу будет проще масштабировать - добавлять новый столбцы, редактировать информацию. Надеюсь, я смог вам помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Логично делать **одну таблицу** для истории поиска пользователей, если она, относительно велика, то её можно держать в отдельной базе данных или оптимизировать иным образом, но создавать таблицы под каждого пользователя совершенно нецелесообразно. Объёмы хранимых данных не меняется, архитектурая сложность растёт, подсчёт статистики может быть сильно затруднён.